# Python: dynamically load library in global path

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have a file `somehash-mylib.py` that contains, say:

```
def hello():
    print("hello world")
```

and I’d like to dynamically import this library **globally** (like in `from mymodule import *`) using only its path. Following [How can I import a module dynamically given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-can-i-import-a-module-dynamically-given-the-full-path) I can do it locally using:

```
from pydoc import importfile
module = importfile('somehash-mylib.py')

module.hello()
```

but I don’t know how load it globally to turn this into:

```
# somehow (??) load somehash-mylib.py

hello()
```

Any idea? Ideally I’d like the code to be simple, and make it work across multiple python versions (only the 3.x branch).

**Edit**
As far as I can see, none of the linked answers that justified to close this question actually answer my question: I have as input only the path to the module, and I want to include it globally. Hopefully, the comment solved my issue (thanks!):

```
from pydoc import importfile
module = importfile('somehash-mylib.py')
locals().update(vars(module)) # make it global

# Both work now
module.hello()
hello()
```

Comment: try to append this to your code: `locals().update(vars(module)) ; hello()`

Comment: @ジョージ Awesome, seems to work perfectly! No idea which dark magic it is doing, put seems to work great! Feel free to write it as an aswer.

Comment: I've reopened your question, please move the answer into an answer. You can ping gold badge holders who close your questions as duplicates.